# MongooseError with uuid when using import instead of require()

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, uuid, nestjs

I get the following error :

```
MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving
```

When I try to create an Object (Campagne) with `uuid` with my API using :

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';
```

It works when I use :

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
```

My Campagne object is created correctly with its `uuid`.

Here is the full code of my object's Schema :

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';

export const CampagneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String, default: uuidv4 },
    dateDebut: Date,
    dateFin: Date,
    reduction: Number,
});
```

TSLint tell me to use `import` instead of `require()` and underline it as an error in my IDE but it's definitely not working as shown above.

Can someone explain me why is this happening please ?

For information, I use the NestJS node.js framework with Typescript.

To clarify :

**I want to know why `import` is working for `mongoose` but not for `uuid` (`require` is working for `uuid`)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer with an issue on Github `node-uuid`.
The following code is working :

```
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';
```

https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid/issues/245

> `import uuid from 'uuid/v4';` syntax does not work, at least in a `Typescript v3` project running on `Node v10.9.0` (without webpack nor babel, only `ts-node` to compile/run Typescript)
>
> I get the following error: `TypeError: v4_1.uuid is not a function`
>
> on the other hand, `import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';` works as expected
>
> (tested on `uuid v3.3.2`)

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `_id: { type: String, default: uuidv4 },`

Mongoose will automatically generate `_id`

And use `const ddd = require(...)`

I believe ES6 modules not working in Node project normally

Comment: But I want to use uuid and not Mongoose id

Comment: `import` works for other cases than this one in my project (mongoose for example), why do I need to use `require()` for this specific case ?

Comment: @XavierFr I think that depends on library's modules structure. https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid#readme The library recommend CommonJS way

Comment: I see. I still don't understand why it doesn't work that way but they say to do it that way in CommonJS so I guess I'll just follow this. I keep the question open if anyone has answer to why exactly I can't use `import`.